# Is there a way to use Facebook Messanger without using Facebook on a Desktop Computer?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

Facebook is a dark existential hole of news that you can become trapped in, which just happens to be the way all your friends and relatives communicate with each other; they continue to use it and I guess that's their problem, I can't tell them what to do.  But I would like to continue communicating with them, so...

Is there a way to use Facebook Messenger without using Facebook?  I can't get the 300 people I know to change what they do.

Answer (score 1):

Download the Facebook Messenger app, select the “Not on Facebook?” option, and enter your phone number and name. That’s it. You can upload and send photos, videos, start group chats, and use voice and video calling without ever having to sign up for a Facebook account.

Answer (score 0):

Simple download the Messenger Desktop app
from the link here :

[Messenger Desktop App](https://www.messenger.com/desktop)

You can use your existing Facebook ID to login ( and import contacts from your Friend List etc. ) and start chatting, without having all the dark stories on your Facebook feed troubling you anytime whatever.